# Matlab: plot against wavelength instead of frequency

Tags: matlab, plot, frequency

I have an array of points that I've associated against frequency. How do I plot that array against wavelength instead of frequency? Keep in mind that I don't want to define functions, just working with arrays here. Here's how I would plot the array known as Q:

```
f = 100:500;  % frequency points
Q = f^2;      % a "function" of frequency
plot(f,Q)
```

Now I know I can simply define a new array `lambda=c/f` where c=speed of light, but can I replot Q against wavelength without having to redefine Q as a function of wavelength?

Comment: would this work `plot(c/f,Q)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, just change the x-axis:

```
plot(c./f, Q);
```